# Using array_udiff in php for multiple fields

Tags: php

Im trying to make a custom function for my script where it it checks one of the indexes of the two arrays and dependent on the custom function it returns all the rows not in both arrays. 
It has worked well for when i have to only check one value as such:

```
function udifflink($a, $b)
{
  return $a['linkid'] - $b['linkid'];
}
//compare links array
$diffinlinks = array_udiff($row, $surveys, 'udifflink');
echo "diff results \n"; 
print_r($diffinlinks);
```

but when i have arrays where i need to check two fields for combined equality (this is a database table where the primary key is two columns) it does not work as expected. I have tried multiple solutions but this is my most recent:

```
function udiffanswers($a, $b)
{
 return $a['aid'].$a['sid'] - $b['aid'].$b['sid'];
}
```

which does not exclude the places where both the aid and sid are the same

```
//array a
[16] => Array
    (
        [aid] => 16
        [qid] => 16
        [sid] => 16
        [freetext] => adfadf
        [a] => adfadf
        [b] => adfadf
        [c] => adfadf
        [d] => adfadf
        [e] => adfadf
        [f] => adfadf
        [g] => adfadf
        [h] => adfadf
        [i] => adfadf
        [j] => adfadf
        [type] => adfadf
        [location] => adfadf
    )
 //array b
 [17] => Array
    (
        [aid] => 16
        [qid] => 17
        [sid] => 16
        [freetext] => adfadf
        [a] => adfadf
        [b] => adfadf
        [c] => adfadf
        [d] => adfadf
        [e] => adfadf
        [f] => adfadf
        [g] => adfadf
        [h] => adfadf
        [i] => adfadf
        [j] => adfadf
        [type] => adfadf
        [location] => adfadf
    )

 [18] => Array
    (
        [aid] => 16
        [qid] => 18
        [sid] => 18
        [freetext] => adfadf
        [a] => adfadf
        [b] => adfadf
        [c] => adfadf
        [d] => adfadf
        [e] => adfadf
        [f] => adfadf
        [g] => adfadf
        [h] => adfadf
        [i] => adfadf
        [j] => adfadf
        [type] => adfadf
        [location] => adfadf
    )
 [19] => Array
    (
        [aid] => 17
        [qid] => 18
        [sid] => 16
        [freetext] => adfadf
        [a] => adfadf
        [b] => adfadf
        [c] => adfadf
        [d] => adfadf
        [e] => adfadf
        [f] => adfadf
        [g] => adfadf
        [h] => adfadf
        [i] => adfadf
        [j] => adfadf
        [type] => adfadf
        [location] => adfadf
    )
```

18 and 19 arrays should be returned from above

this is something else ive tried... not really sure how to get the result from multiple ifs...

```
function udiffanswers($a, $b)
{   
if($a['aid'] - $b['aid']){
if($a['sid'] - $b['sid']){
return $a;
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: sure added some the above should return only array 18 and 19 but it returns both. the reason 17 shouldnt be beacuse the combination of aid and sid isnt different than a's combination, while 18s and 19s combination is differnt

Comment: does order matter? 16,17 vs 17,16? regardless, you either need to use fancier math to solve your problem, or just use some if statements and treat the field as the separate pieces of data that they are.

Comment: yes order matters. yeah i was thinking of doing if statements to check the first and then move onto the next parameter but wasnt too sure the best way to get the results using this method